# Why this code in tensorflow doesn't work?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

My code is written as this.

```
def __init__(self, X):
    ops.reset_default_graph()
    tl.layers.clear_layers_name()

    self.sess = tf.Session()

    self.input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784],name="input")  

    input_layer = tl.layers.InputLayer(self.input_x)
    drop1 = tl.layers.DropoutLayer(input_layer, keep=0.8, name="drop1")
    relu1 = tl.layers.DenseLayer(drop1, n_units=800, act = tf.nn.relu)
    drop2 = tl.layers.DropoutLayer(relu1, keep=0.5, name="drop2")

    self.output = drop2.all_layers[-1]

    self.gradient = tf.gradients(self.output,self.input_x)

    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    self.sess.run(init_op)
    self.output.eval(session=self.sess, feed_dict={self.input_x:X})
```

As you can see, there is only one placeholder initiated, however, I met

> InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor
>   'Placeholder' with dtype float     [[Node: Placeholder =
>   Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

I am one hundred percent sure that the `X` I fed in has type float32, and the shape [1000,784].

Comment: Seems like there is placeholder somewhere other than `self.input_x`, you'll have to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Olivier correctly pointed out, the name of the placeholder tensor missing a feed value is different from the name of the placeholder tensor you directly created ("input").

If you're using [TensorLayer](http://tensorlayer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), you probably won't be able to just call session.run or some_tensor.eval without understanding TensorLayer layer insternals. For example, each of their `DropoutLayer` instances creates internally a [`tf.placeholder` for the keep probability](https://github.com/zsdonghao/tensorlayer/blob/master/tensorlayer/layers.py#L839).

That said this library seems to expect you only interact with your model via their APIs (e.g. `fit` and `test`) like in the following example:

```
# Train the network, we recommend to use tl.iterate.minibatches()
tl.utils.fit(sess, network, train_op, cost, X_train, y_train, x, y_,
            acc=acc, batch_size=500, n_epoch=500, print_freq=5,
            X_val=X_val, y_val=y_val, eval_train=False)

# Evaluation
tl.utils.test(sess, network, acc, X_test, y_test, x, y_, batch_size=None, cost=cost)
```

From: https://github.com/zsdonghao/tensorlayer#your-first-program

Answer (score 2):

you have **TWO** ways to use **DropoutLayer** in TensorLayer:

1) Use the internal keep prob placeholder created by TensorLayer, see [tutorial_mlp_dropout1.py](https://github.com/tensorlayer/tensorlayer/blob/master/example/tutorial_mlp_dropout1.py)

2) Instead of using placeholder to control the keep prob, we build two graphs for training and testing, see [tutorial_mlp_dropout2.py](https://github.com/tensorlayer/tensorlayer/blob/master/example/tutorial_mlp_dropout2.py)

So in your case, if you don't want to use the internal placeholder created by TensorLayer, you can use the second way.